# How to decode URL in javascript(*.js file) which was encoded in code behind using HttpUtility.UrlEncode ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, vb.net, decode, encode

How do I decode a URL using JavaScript which is encoded in code behind using HttpUtility.UrlEncode?

Since I am encoding the URL with HttpUtility.UrlEncode, I need to decode it in * .js file.

Here is what I am doing in code behind (VB.NET):

```
Response.AppendHeader("RESP-URL", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Url.LocalPath))
```

Here is what I am doing in javascript (*.js file):

```
var url = resphdr.getResponseHeader("RESP-URL");
```

so in order to decode the code encoded in code behind, can I use the below code in *.js file?

```
var url = resphdr.getResponseHeader("RESP-URL");
**url = decodeURIComponent(url)**
```

If the above works, please confirm or If not suggest me the solution.

Also is it works on across all versions of web browsers?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Also, for checking which browsers something works in, [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/) is useful.